# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on my first google script function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, functional-programming, google-apps

I'm starting study about Google Apps Script, and in my first function (a simple recursive Fibonacci), I'm receiving the following error:

`RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Ok, ok expected risk using a recursive approach, can anybody help me where I mistake?

My code below:

```js
function FIBONACCI(input) {
  const number = parseInt(input);

  if (number < 2) { return number; }
  return FIBONACCI(number - 1) + FIBONACCI(number - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two recursive steps in the algorithm of the Fibunacci sequence.

```
return FIBONACCI(number - 1) + FIBONACCI(number - 2);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So even for a relatively small number a lot of frames are pushed onto the call stack. Here is a visualization:

```js
const log = x => (console.log(`fib(${x})`), x);

function FIBONACCI(input) {
  const number = parseInt(input);

  if (number < 2) { return number; }
  return log(FIBONACCI(number - 1)) + log(FIBONACCI(number - 2));
}

FIBONACCI("10");
```

Consequently you rather quickly exhaust the call stack.

Please note that Fibonacci numbers are more naturally expressed with corecursion a.k.a. unfolding:

```js
const fibs = i => {
  const go = (x, y, j) =>
    j === 1
      ? [x]
      : [x].concat(go(y, x + y, j - 1));

  return go(1, 1, i);
};

console.log(
  fibs(100)); // 55
```

This is still not stack safe though. Since Javascript doesn't pursue tail call elimination you would have to use a trampoline.

Comment: Hey @bob, thanks 4 your response,  as a developer, I knew about risk w/ recursive Fibonacci implementation. But as a simple test, I didn`t think that Google was getting trouble it, but I had changed to interactive (using a loop `for`a) solution. 

obs.: I`m not very familiar w/ JS and I thought very interest your approach to code ternary operator very similar with OCaml.